# Check service status after the apps is closed in Android

Tags: android, service, audio-player, android-music-player

I am working on a music player

The logic is like this:
First, I click on the play button , if there is music playing, stop the service , otherwise , start it.

**Play / Pause Button:**

```
playM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                    if (!manager.isMusicActive()) {
                        playM.setText("Pause");
                        Intent svc=new Intent(getContext(), Music.class);
                        svc.putExtra("uri", tt1.getText().toString());
                        getContext().startService(svc);
                    } else {
                        playM.setText("Play");
                        //if (mPlayer != null && mPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        Intent svc=new Intent(getContext(), Music.class);
                        getContext().stopService(svc);
                        //}
                    }
                }
            });
```

**Service:**

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        path = (String) intent.getExtras().get("uri"); 
        Uri uriMusic = Uri.parse(path);
        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, uriMusic);
        player.start();
        player.setLooping(true); // Set looping
        return 1;
    }

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    player.stop();
    player.release();
}
```

The problem is, if the music is playing by another apps, my music player will crash. But I can not find any way to track the service status. For example, if I play the music, close the app , the music is still playing , but when I open the app again , how to know the specific service (play music which is fire by my app only, in this case) is running? Thanks

Comment: What is your crash report saying ? Please post the error log also.

Comment: You need to stop the service also in your onDestroy.

Comment: Thanks. If I stop service when my app destroy , then it can not perform background music playing

Comment: Since the audio manager is checking whether the media player is using in global , if I have other app running music playing, I will fall into the stop playing condition, but in fact the music service in my app is not running